# why textbox is not updated with value when windows is shown first

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, caliburn.micro

I have a DoubleTextbox (from Extended WPF Toolkit) which is added to a gris as follow:

```
<xctk:DoubleUpDown Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FormatString="F2" Value="{Binding MyDoubleValue}" Maximum="100" Minimum=".0001" DefaultValue="1.0"/>
```

and the MyDouble value is defined as follow:

```
private double myDouble=1.0;
public double MyDouble 
{
    get
    {
        return this.myDouble ;
    }

    set
    {
        if (Math.Abs(this.myDouble - value) > 0.0000000000001)
        {
            this.myDouble = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.MyDouble );
        }
    }
}
```

when I run application and look at value for this textbox, it is blank, but if I use up arrow it shows 2.0 (which means that it correctly detected value for MyDouble.

Why it doesn't show its value on window at start up?

I am using caliburn micro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the DefaultValue="1.0" on XAML. when I removed it, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Name of property is not correct. It should be MyDouble instead of MyDoubleValue

```
Value="{Binding MyDouble}"
```

Comment: It was probably a typo.

Comment: It was a type. The fact that MyDoubleValue gets the value of textbox when I changed it, shows that my binding worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a default value:

```
private double myDouble=1.0;
```

Therefore, `NotifyOfPropertyChange` has not yet been called for `MyDouble` and WPF does not know about the value.

Set the value (via the Property, not the backer field) in the constructor of the `ViewModel` or somewhere else during initialization.

Or

Call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.MyDouble );` during initialization.

Comment: If the property has a value before first binding, there is no reason to raise the property changed event. In fact object creation happens before binding happens and so any event raised during object creation, is not seen by any other object as they are not subscribed to it at that stage.